# SQS messages not returning all messages using AWS SDK Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I'm trying to retrieve all messages from my SQS queue using AWS Java SDK, but it always return only one message. I've set `maxNumberOfMessages(10)` still it return only one message. Please find my code below - what I'm missing here. In my queue I've more than 10k records.

And how can I read more than 10 messages, looks like the max limit is we can read up-to 10 message only. If I want to process 10k records how can we do that?

It would be really appreciated if you could assist me with these two issues. Thanks!

```
public void getMessage(String queue) {

ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = ReceiveMessageRequest.builder()
        .queueUrl(queue)
        .waitTimeSeconds(10)
        .maxNumberOfMessages(10)
        .build();

List<Message> messages = sqsClient.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).messages();
for (Message msg : messages) {
    System.out.println("msgID: "+msg.messageId());
    System.out.println("message: "+msg.body());
}
```

}

Comment: `And how can I read more than 10 messages, looks like the max limit is we can read up-to 10 message only. If I want to process 10k records how can we do that?`- correct, speaking from experience to get around this you will need to do multi-threading to send more than 10 records at a time. you can't increase the 10 message batch limit.